# Web UI в андроиде

Tags: web-apps, android, javascript

Пробовал ли кот-то интегрировать веб-UI в андроид? Не просто загружать страничку с сервера и отображать в браузере, а именно интегрировать ее в браузер андроида. Я говорю не о закладке в браузере, а об пользовательском интерфейсе который написан на javascript и интегрирован в браузер, т.е. пользователь не видет, что это веб-UI. Прошу поделиться подходами и решениями данной задачи.

Comment: не который IDE, при создании проекта, уже имеют шаблон вьюхи для отображения на мобильных...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если правильно понял задачу - создать гибридное приложение на html5, которое можно будет выложить в маркет. Копать надо в сторону [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com), позволяющий использовать в js функции железа - gps, акселлерометр, камеру.
Ну и чтоб не писать страницу с нуля js-фреймворки [JQTouch](http://jqtouch.com), [Sencha touch](http://sencha.com/touch), [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com). Тут имеется в виду, что обработка tap'ов и swype'ов в js для мобильных платформ отличается от десктопных браузеров. Скорость работы фреймворков разная как и возможности. В андроиде очень серьезные тормоза с интерфейсом, проблемы с поддержкой трехмерной анимации (CSS3), кроме того в разных версиях платформы разные версии браузеров, придется тестить каждую мажорную версию андроида на совместимость с написанным приложением.